# Breeze Complex Type Array Validation - Issue

Tags: angularjs, breeze, complextype, breeze-sharp

I am trying to do the validation for the data properties present in complex type array. Below shown is the sample breeze schema and the complex type used.

Breeze schema:

```
    {
        "name": "mailingAddress",
        "complexTypeName": "Address:#test",
        "isScalar":false
    }
```

Complex type: (Address.json)

```
    {
        "name": "address",
        "dataType": "String",
        "validators": [
            {
                //some custom validator
            }
        ]
    }
```

In this case ,the sample data object will be like as shown below

```
{
mailingAddress:[
      {
        address:"123 street"
      },
      {
        address:"Main Street"
      }
  ]
```

}

If I change the address, the validator associated to the address data property will trigger.

My question is: I am changing the address of the first object (`mailingAddress[0]`), how does breeze knows that I have changed the first address object? Is there any way to take the changed array index?

I had checked the `propertyName` present in context, but it does not have the exact path.

- Expectation : `mailingAddress[0].address`
- Actual : `mailingAddress.address`

I am not able to do the custom validation properly because of the above problem. Kindly provide a solution for this issue.

Thanks, Dinesh

Comment: Excellent question. I tripped over this ... and thought I found the answer. I've forgotten already. We should document it. Expect more information soon.

Comment: @Ward - Thanks , waiting for your valuable information.

Comment: Waiting for the right person to return from vacation. I hope we'll see an answer soon.

Comment: One more interesting thing to note: **** "index is available directly under the context object if we do the validation for the entire entity, but during the validation on a propertyChange the index is not available" ****I am currently using breeze v1.5.1 . Refer below lines present in breeze.debug.js ****Line no:3964 (validateTarget())- **array index is set to the context.index, this code will execute during the validation of entire entity.**. ******Line no:5402 (updateStateAndValidate()) - **array index is not set in the context,this code will execute during the validation on propertyChange**

Comment: Added the code snippet for reference:(breeze.debug.js v1.5.1). 
1)Line no:3964-**This is code snippet for validation of entire entity**
 `var context ={entity: entityAspect.entity};
    if (coIndex !==undefined) {
      context.index = coIndex;
    }`
2).Line no:5400- **This is the code snippet for validation on propertyChange**.
`if (entityManager.validationOptions.validateOnPropertyChange) {
    entityAspect._validateProperty(context.newValue,
        { entity: entityAspect.entity,index:context.index, property: property, propertyName: context.propertyName, oldValue: context.oldValue });
  }`

Comment: I'm tripping over this as well... @Ward Has this person come back from vacation yet? ;)